# Upgrade IBus or "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" to fix IntelliJ/Android Studio input issue

Tags: ibus, android-studio, intellij

When using IntelliJ or Android Studio, the application gives a warning that using an IBus version prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems. [Multiple solutions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) are offered including:

- Upgrade to IBus version 1.5.11 or higher
- add `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` to your `~/.profile`, then restart a session

Which of these two options would be better to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always choose the easiest method only if I got a disadvantage that bother me.

```
echo "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" >> ~/.profile
```

Upgrading or downgrading to version not available in repository, in general  may create many complications like unresolved dependencies. You may then forced to installed from source. I would not close a door, so plan b is upgrading.